# How to use Protocol Buffers 3 in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, protocol-buffers, protoc

I'm trying to use Protocol Buffers v3 in Ruby.

I'm using standard `protoc` with the `--ruby_out` option to generate Ruby source code files from `*.proto` files. Those generated files have `require 'google/protobuf'` requirement, so I need to use the `google-protobuf` gem in order to run this Ruby code.

I'm reading the docs for `google-protobuf` here:

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/ruby-generated

but I don't see any option to decode a protobuf packet from the stream (i.e. stdin)? It may be fine to decode the packet from a standard buffer, but does this library support decoding packets from a stream? If yes, can anyone point me to a direction on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [GRPC](https://grpc.io/) , the Doc is [here](https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/ruby.html#)

The gRPC service is defined using protocol buffers